# Is it possible to create a javascript back button for an HTML slideshow?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a rather large slideshow type site. All the slides are on one html page so I can't use the browser back function. Each slide has a back button. I can't specifically specify where that back button should go because the slide show is non-linear. So I could arrive at any particular slide from any other slide. Is there a way of making a history array or anything that I could use for this back button that would function as a back button?

I should say, I am a beginner. I'm still learning javascript.

Edit: I forgot to mention that I'm trying to do this purely in javascript/html/css.

I've got the back button working in javascript, but only one step backwards. I just made it so each button clicked updates a variable with the current slide's ID. Then the back button just "points" to that variable. The problem is, it won't go back more than one step because once you go back once the variable is never updated to the ID that you just went back from. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: History API - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/History

Answer (score 1):

You can use the History API:

When jumps from slide #1 to #5, call `history.pushState`:

```
var stateObject = {page: "5"};
history.pushState(stateObject, "Slide #5", "#5");
```

When navigates back, simply call `history.back()`, and add a `popstate` listener to show the desired slide:

```
window.addEventListener("popstate", function(event) {
    $(".page").hide();
    $("#p" + event.state.page).show();
}
```

The `event.state` here is the `stateObject` you pushed when you call `history.pushState`. For example, when user navigates back to Slide #5, the `event.state` is `{page: "5"}`.

```js
    function jump() {
      var target = this.getAttribute("data-value");
      document.querySelector(".on").classList.remove("on");
      document.getElementById("s"+target).classList.add("on");
      var stateObject = {page: target};
      history.pushState(stateObject, "Slide #" + target, "#" + target);
    }
    document.querySelectorAll(".jump").forEach(function(element) {
      element.addEventListener("click", jump);
    });
    document.querySelector(".back").addEventListener("click", function() {
      history.back();
    });

    window.addEventListener("popstate", function(event) {
      if (event.state === null) {
        // the first page has no stateObject
        document.querySelector(".on").classList.remove("on");
        document.getElementById("s1").classList.add("on");
      } else if (typeof event.state.page !== "undefined") {
        document.querySelector(".on").classList.remove("on");
        document.getElementById("s" + event.state.page).classList.add("on");
      }
    });
```

```css
.page {display: none;}
.page.on {display: block;}
```

```html
  <button class="back">Back</button>
  <div class="page on" id="s1">
    Slide #1
    <div class="action">
      <button class="jump" data-value="3">Go to #3</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="page" id="s2">
    Slide #2
    <div class="action">
      <button class="jump" data-value="1">Go to #1</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="page" id="s3">
    Slide #3
    <div class="action">
      <button class="jump" data-value="2">Go to #2</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

See:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/popstate